# Get drive letter of Hard drive

Tags: c++, mfc

My application is for windows Vista and XP.

There are more than on Hard drive connected to my machine. I need to get Drive Letters of the Hard drive from which my system is booting.

By using GetLogicalDriveStrings Function I can get the drive letters of all Hard drives. But how can I differentiate that this particular drive letter is the partition name of my booting Hard drive?

The structure of disks are:

disk0(Booting with this)- C D G

disk1- E F H

disk2- I J

I need to get the C,D,G only.

Comment: Another question of many where either [karthik](http://stackoverflow.com/users/644073/karthik) or [user692270](http://stackoverflow.com/users/692270/user692270) accepts @karthik 's answer. Seriously, you are suffering from an inferiority complex; get to your doctor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call **GetLogicalDrives** to get all the available drive letters.

Call **GetSystemDirectory** to get the drive which contains the OS.

Open the volume using **CreateFile("\.\C:", ...**

Here replace C: with the drive letter returned in GetSystemDirectory.

Call **DeviceIControl** of the returned handle with the **IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS** code to get the hard disk number.

Now you know the hard disk number of the drive containing the OS.

Repeat the **CreateFile** and **DeviceIoControl** on all the other drive letters and compare the hard disk number with the one you got earlier.

Comment: Another question of many where either [karthik](http://stackoverflow.com/users/644073/karthik) or [user692270](http://stackoverflow.com/users/692270/user692270) accepts @karthik 's answer. Seriously, you are suffering from an inferiority complex; get to your doctor.